# How to append np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an np.array `d1` of (3,6), and an np.array `a4` of (6,).

How can I combine the two np.arrays to form an np.array `d2` of (4,6)?

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a1=np.array(range(6))
a2=a1+2
a3=a2+3
a4=a3+4
d1=np.array([a1,a2,a3])
d1.shape
```

```
Out[44]: (3, 6)
```

```
d2=np.array([a1,a2,a3,a4])
d2.shape
d2
```

```
Out[45]: (4, 6)
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

How to get `d2` from `d1` and `a4`?

I tried `np.insert` and `np.append`, but maybe my usage is wrong and I didn't get the correct result.

Comment: reshape a4 to 2D and then `concatenate`: [`np.concatenate([d1, a4.reshape(1, -1)])`](https://akuiper.com/console/wZu2Ks86o-qb)

Comment: You checked the `d1` shape, but not the `a4` shape.  `np.array([a1,a2,a3])` joined 3 (6,) shape arrays on a new leading axis, forming a (3,6) one.  The distinction between (6,), (1,6) and (6,1) shapes is important, especially when joining arrays

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, a4.shape is (6,), and I corrected.

Comment: I found an other way: d2=np.concatenate([d1,a4[np.newaxis]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to reshape a4 which has currently the shape of `(6,)`

```
a4 = a4.reshape(1,-1)  # shape=(1,6)
```

then use [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```py
d2 = np.concatenate((d1, a4), axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html concatenate is the command you are looking for.

```
foo = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6]])
bar = np.array([7,8,9])

# axis 0 will combine rows, axis 1 will combine columns
foobar = numpy.concatenate(foo,bar,axis = 0)

array([[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]])
```

Comment: foobar = np.concatenate((foo,bar.reshape(1,-1)),axis = 0)

Answer (score 1):

a4 is a 1D array, so you can expand it

```
import numpy as np 

d1 = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
               [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
               [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])

a4 = np.array(np.arange(9,15))

d2 = np.concatenate((d1, np.expand_dims(a4,0)), 0)

print(d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be belaboring the point, but:

```
In [156]: d1.shape
Out[156]: (3, 6)
In [157]: a4.shape
Out[157]: (6,)               # not (1,6)
In [158]: np.append(d1,a4)
Out[158]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
       10,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

`np.append` says it flattens the arrays, unless we provide an `axis`.

```
In [159]: np.append(d1,a4, axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-159-dd72c66fd0c0>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(d1,a4, axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 5392, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Note that `append` has called `np.concatenate`.  That's all it really does.  `np.append` should be removed - it misleads too many novices.

Any ways, `concatenate` expects the arrays to match in number of dimensions. The error should be clear about the problem.  The solution is, as the other answers show, to turn the (6,) into a (1,6).